# MySQL: Using case when to sum/average values shared and not shared?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query I am trying to expand on and have hit a roadblock. What I want do is return rows that contain counts, sums and averages for data provided around attributes that are shared and not shared.

I have it pretty close but returning nulls and 0's where I need to see data.

Let me explain...but please let me know if I need to clarify.

First here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `fruits` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fruit` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fruit_attribute` varchar(11) DEFAULT '',
  `submissions` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `fruits` (`id`, `fruit`, `fruit_attribute`, `submissions`)
VALUES
    (1,'Orange','tough peel',59),
    (2,'Lemon','tough peel',70),
    (3,'Orange','citrus',100),
    (4,'Orange','juice',90),
    (5,'Lemon','juice',75),
    (6,'Lemon','tart',35),
    (7,'Lemon','citurs',65),
    (8,'Orange','breakfast',110),
    (9,'Lemon','lemonaid',120),
    (10,'Orange','florida',50);
```

Next, my query:

```
SELECT ft.fruit,  
       COUNT(distinct ft1.fruit_attribute) As att_shared_lemon,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ft1.fruit_attribute IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As not_shared_lemon,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ft1.fruit_attribute IS NOT NULL THEN ft.submissions END) as sum_shared_submissions, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ft1.fruit_attribute IS NULL THEN ft.submissions END) as sum_notshared_submissions 
       FROM fruits  ft LEFT JOIN
     fruits ft1
     ON ft.fruit_attribute = ft1.fruit_attribute and ft1.fruit = 'Orange'
GROUP BY ft.fruit
having fruit='Orange'
ORDER BY att_shared_lemon desc;
```

Here is an SQL Fiddle of the above:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86e863/12

Desired output would not include the 0 and Null value seen in below:

```
+--------+------------------+------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+
| fruit  | attr_shared_orange | attr_not_shared_orange| sum_shared_submissions | sum_notshared_submissions |
+--------+------------------+------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+
| Orange |                5 |                0 |                    409 | (null)                    |
+--------+------------------+------------------+------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Instead there would be the total amount of attributes that were not shared by 'Orange' and the sum of submissions for the attributes not shared with 'Orange'

I am running mysql 5.6 on a mac Yosemite.

Ideally I would like to achieve this without a subselect but if it's required and have no option then I would like to understand more about that.

Comment: The HAVAING clause is intended for aggregate function conditions. Put  fruit='Orange' in WHERE clause instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a minor issue with your join logic here, you want to sum links between fruits but your query ensures that you're always joining oranges to oranges and as such there will never be attributes which **aren't** shared:

`ON ft.fruit_attribute = ft1.fruit_attribute and ft1.fruit = 'Orange'`

Try this query instead:

```
SELECT ft.fruit,  
       COUNT(distinct ft1.fruit_attribute) As att_shared_lemon,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ft1.fruit_attribute IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As not_shared_lemon,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ft1.fruit_attribute IS NOT NULL THEN ft.submissions END) as sum_shared_submissions, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ft1.fruit_attribute IS NULL THEN ft.submissions END) as sum_notshared_submissions 
       FROM fruits  ft 

       LEFT JOIN fruits ft1
        ON ft.fruit_attribute = ft1.fruit_attribute and ft.fruit = 'Orange'
        AND ft1.fruit != ft.fruit

WHERE ft.fruit='Orange'     

GROUP BY ft.fruit
ORDER BY att_shared_lemon desc;
```